# Limit point need not belong to a set

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces, definition

I was reading multivariable calculus , where there were a few topological definitions on things like open ball, limit points, boundaries etc.i came across the statement "a limit point of a set need not belong to the set". Why is this true? can someone give a visual and mathematical proof of this.

Comment: For example, what are the limit points of the subset $(0,1)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: the limit points of (0,1) are all real numbers between 0 and 1, inclusive. So, any value in the closed interval [0,1] is a limit point. However, the endpoints 0 and 1 themselves are not considered limit points since the subset excludes them. Is this right i am a novice to this topic.

Comment: Yes, the limit points are the elements of the set $[0,1]$. So that answers your question, points outside of the set (like $0$ and $1$ in this case) can also be limit points.

Comment: thnx a lot , but how can i prove this mathematically ?

Comment: Depends which definition of a limit point you are using. The easiest way is to prove that $0$ is a limit point is to note that it's the limit of the sequence $\frac{1}{n+1}$ of elements in the set $(0,1)$.

Comment: i am using this definition :
Let B ⊂ Rn.
We say that P ∈ Rn is a limit point
if for every  ε > 0 the intersection
B(P, ε) ∩ B != ∅.

Comment: For the interval $~(0,1),~$ to prove that $~0~$ is a limit point, note that for all $~\epsilon > 0,~$ you have that $~(\epsilon/2)~ \in (0,\epsilon) \cap (0,1).~$ Thus, for all $~\epsilon > 0,~$ you have that $~(0,\epsilon) \cap (0,1)~$ is never equal to the emptyset.

Answer (score 0):

When we talk about limit point of a set we mean some point in the Metric Space around whose neighbourhood there are infinitely many points of the set located.

To be more precise, no matter how close the boundary of that point is considered there will be some point(rather infinitely many) of the set within the boundary.

Mathematically,

if $A \subset X$ then $y \in X$ is said to be a limit point of $A$ if for each $\epsilon$ >0

$N(y,\epsilon)\cap A\setminus\{y\} \neq \phi$.

For example

Consider $\{\frac{1}{n} : n \in N\}$

This has limit point $0$ which does not belong to the set.